# EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "Task" was found - NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am learning the NestJS course from Udemy https://www.udemy.com/course/nestjs-zero-to-hero.

And I am stuck with a strange issue and I have tried many things but nothing seems to be working. Here is the issue and complete code that I have.

**Error that I am getting**

[image: Error that I am getting]

**My ORM configuration file:**

[image: ORM Configuration file]

**Task Entity File: **
[image]

**Finally I am importing the configuration file in tasks.module.ts file**
[image]

People facing there issue have resolved it with different fixes,

1. Some said that we might be adding misspelled file name or path in configuration that might have caused this issue.
2. Some said that changing from npm to yarn has fixed the issue.
3. And few also said that the issue is with ORM itself.

I have tried all possible solutions that are available over the internet but was not able to fix this. Its been quite few days now and I am looking for a helping hand or savior on stack overflow.

Meanwhile, I will try to see a few more possibilities that could help but if you have faced this issue do let me know the possible solutions.

Comment: In the future, please post actual code snippets and not screenshots. Please take a [look at this link](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @JayMcDoniel sure. Will make sure to add code's. I added screenshot as i knew that something small might be an issue and I had my code on github . just in case if someone wanted to debug I would have given the github link. But will make sure that i add code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're missing the `@Entity()` decorator on your `Task` class. This sets the metadata that TypeORM is looking for [according to its docs](https://typeorm.io).

Comment: Hi Jay. Thank you it helped. Sometimes I feel like an idiot. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: didnt work for me even tho i have @Entity. same issue, No metadata was found

Answer (score 24):

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts']
```

to

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.js']
```

in **typeorm.config.ts**

it works on me

Answer (score 16):

In [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) adding `.js` along side `.ts` worked for me

`typeorm.config.ts`

Before

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const TypeORMConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts'],
  migrationsTableName: 'Migrations_History',
};
```

After

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const TypeORMConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrationsTableName: 'Migrations_History',
};
```

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the same issue. After trying all the other mentioned solutions here which they do not worked for me, I have modified the **typeorm.config.ts** file by adding the following option:

```
  autoLoadEntities: true,
```

This has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

that error is caused by typescript
if you set typeOrmCOnfig
just like this
[image]

use file after compile, that is to say , use dist/*.js

Comment: set typeOrmCOnfig

         entities: [`dist/**/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`], // try this

Answer (score 2):

You are extending **BaseEntity** this doesn't mean that it will place the @Entity annotation to your entity class. it is basically used like for example certain data fields you want every of your entities to have.

it's internal implementation is something like below :-

```
// base.entity.ts
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, UpdateDateColumn, CreateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

export abstract class BaseEntity {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;

@Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true })
isActive: boolean;

@Column({ type: 'boolean', default: false })
isArchived: boolean;

@CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
createDateTime: Date;

@Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
createdBy: string;

@UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
lastChangedDateTime: Date;

@Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
lastChangedBy: string;

@Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300, nullable: true })
   internalComment: string | null;
}
```

so this will generate an  uuid id-field and/or a createDateTime-, lastChangedDateTime-fields.

Note: that these base classes should be abstract.

**so you have to place @Entity annotation at the starting of your each Entity class**

also change the order of imports like first import the TypeOrmModule and then TaskModule.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi Sunny. Thank you for your answer. 
Not sure how did I miss that.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    @Module({
  imports: [
    TasksModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'postgres',
      database: 'userdata',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,

    }),
  ],
  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: we can do the ORM configurations in **app.module** file and Try with the above approach. For me, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

According to typeOrm official doc [loading-all-entities-from-the-directory](https://typeorm.io/#/undefined/loading-all-entities-from-the-directory) be careful with this approach while working with ts-node. The outDir might be pointing to a different location/file from where your entities are placed, resulting in the above-mentioned error. You'll need to specify paths to .js files inside outDir directory.

Set entities to :

```
entities: [__dirname + '../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your entities like this:

```
 entities: ['dist/src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
```